# How to Combine Date & Time fields to DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

I have a `TextBox` Control on `asp.net` Form which inputs the `Date` From User. and another `TextBox`  control to enter `Time`.
Now, i want to Combine both these fields and save to DataBase.

**Example: 05/25/1987+10.30PM**

**Results to 05/25/1987 10:30PM**

Existing Code:

```
   public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

    DateTime? dd = new DateTime();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDueDate.Text))
    {
        dd = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDueDate.Text.ToString().Trim());          
    }
    else
    {
        dd =null ;
    }
    objBB.DueDate = dd;
```

HTML markup:

```
<strong> Due Date:</strong>&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="txtDueDate" runat="server" CssClass="txtadmincms" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>         
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDueDate">
 </cc1:CalendarExtender>

 <strong> Time:</strong>&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server" CssClass="txtadmincms" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeStartTimePunchIn" runat="server" AcceptAMPM="true"
   MaskType="Time" Mask="99:99" MessageValidatorTip="true" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
  OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" UserTimeFormat="None"
  TargetControlID="txtTime" InputDirection="LeftToRight" AcceptNegative="Left">
</cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

**UPDATED:**
if `TIME` field `TextBox` is empty it gives error in else part

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDueDate.Text))
        {

            dd = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDueDate.Text.ToString().Trim());
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTime.Text))
            {
                ddateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDueDate.Text.ToString() + txtTime.Text.ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                ddateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDueDate.Text.ToString(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            dd = ddateTime;
            //Combine here date & time

        }
        else
        {
            dd =null ;
        }
        objBB.DueDate = dd;
```

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
string dateAndTime = txtDueDate.Text.Trim() + ' ' + txtTime.Text.Trim(); // 05/25/1987 10:30PM
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAndTime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
dt = DateTime.Parse(dateAndTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Error:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. while debug the variable dateAndTime is "01/15/2014 10:30AM" ! What s wrong? :(

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE: I don't know, my code works with your variable in any culture since i'm using `InvariantCulture`. So there must be something wrong with the input-string. Here you can see it in action with your string: http://ideone.com/YhaAgt

Answer (score 2):

You may try combining two strings into one and then parsing it:

```
string datePart = txtDueDate.Text.ToString().Trim();
string timePart = txtTime.Text.ToString().Trim();
string dateTime = string.Format("{0} {1}", datePart, timePart);
dd = DateTime.Parse(dateTime);
```

Couple of things to conside:

- Make sure to provide format if needed
- Check for empty values of textboxes
- You might want to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` for input validation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  DateTime dt = 
        DateTime.ParseExact(txtDueDate.Text.ToString()+txtTime.Text.ToString(), 
        "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Error: string was not recognized as valid datetime..:(

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE please check if your strings are valid to be converted to datetime. Have u tried with other solutions?